# Aligning the baseline of field labels with the baseline of text in text inputs

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-alignment, baseline

I'm displaying text inputs next to some label text in a fieldset. I'd like the baseline of the text in the text inputs to line up with the baseline of the label text. I could set a fudge factor `padding-top` for my `.label` elements but the content of my `.value` elements may contain read-only text and this would screw up the label/value baseline alignment for those fields. I also suspect the different fudge factors would be required for different browsers because of height differences between input fields across browsers.

**Does anyone have any ideas how I can get my label and input text baselines to align?** My label text may span multiple lines and as such I'd like any solution to take this into account.

You can see a live example the following code at http://jsbin.com/enobe3.

**CSS**

```
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
}

.field {
    clear: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.label {
    float: left;
    width: 90px;
}

.value {
    margin-left: 90px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="label">A short label</div>
        <div class="value">Some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="label">A long long long long long long long wrapping label</div>
        <div class="value">Some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="label">A short label</div>
        <div class="value"><input value="Some text"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="label">A long long long long long long long wrapping label</div>
        <div class="value"><input value="Some text"/></div>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 11):

The baseline alignment issue is related to the default line height for the text boxes and input field.

`input` fields have a larger default height to accommodate padding, border and text.

I experimented with your HTML/CSS code snippets and posted my version at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/EbuJH/

I added some background colors, some padding and margins to outline the blocks.

The key is to set the `line-height` property so that your labels and input fields have the same value, 2.0 in my example.

```
.field {
    clear: left;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background-color: lightgray;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: 2.00; /* Key property */
}
```

You can adjust the line height to get a sense of how it works.

I tested the example in Firefox and IE8 and the results are consistent with a strict doctype.

The result works well for single line labels.  The one drawback is that the multi-line labels may have more spacing than you like.  You could work around this by putting the first line of the multi-line label in a span and applying the line height only to the span, but that is extra work.

At least we know understand what controls the baseline positioning, so we can make progress.